# How to send binary file URL in the curl command instead passing local path

Tags: linux, curl, macintosh, http

I am trying to post a binary .apk file which is on s3 bucket to a POST API.

Local way which I know is:

```
curl -X POST https://xxx.example.com:443/api/storage/upload -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary @file_name.file
```

But

I when I try the following, it is not working

```
curl -X POST https://xxx.example.com:443/api/storage/upload -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary @example.com/app-debug.apk
```

**I am getting below Error.**

> ```
> Warning: Couldn't read data from file
> Warning: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.greenhouseci.com/projects/6d
> Warning: 7f406a-2a65-4be0-83ee-75ca0afae7c9/builds/24f78eb5-819f-44d5-9c21-edce
> Warning: 4dc9f253/artefacts/app-debug.apk", this makes an empty POST.
> ```

Comment: 'It's not working' ... what are we supposed to do with this information? _What_ is not working? What error do you get?

Comment: ... And what is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site: Can you improve the question, by telling us what you expect to happen, and what happened.

Comment: If you use the same account, then you can edit your own questions.

Comment: Is that the exact command you ran and the exact error message? Or is that you masked the actual filename from the command, but not from the error message?

Answer (score 6):

What's happening here is that you're misusing the `@` flag for the `--data-binary` option. The `man page` for `curl` describes its use quite clearly

> If you start the data with the letter `@`, the rest should be a file name to read the data  from, or `-` if you want `curl` to read the data from *stdin*.

What you wrote instructed `curl` to use the *file* called `app-debug.apk` from the subdirectory `example.com`:

> ```
> curl ... --data-binary @example.com/app-debug.apk
> ```

It then told you that it couldn't find that file, but then proceeded to complete the rest of the command, resulting in an empty `POST`:

> ```
> Warning: Couldn't read data from file
> Warning: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.greenhouseci.com/projects/6d
> Warning: 7f406a-2a65-4be0-83ee-75ca0afae7c9/builds/24f78eb5-819f-44d5-9c21-edce
> Warning: 4dc9f253/artefacts/app-debug.apk", this makes an empty POST.
> ```

Nowhere does it say that `@` can be used to reference a URI, so what you need to do is to get the artifact yourself and then `POST` it to your server. Something like either of these suggestions could work

1. Download the POST content and then upload it

   ```
   curl https://example.com/app-debug.apk >app-debug.apk
   curl -X POST https://xxx.example.com:443/api/storage/upload -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary @app-debug.apk
   ```
2. Stream the POST content and upload it

   ```
   curl https://example.com/app-debug.apk |
       curl -X POST https://xxx.example.com:443/api/storage/upload -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary @-
   ```

Comment: How to make this work with sending data to an FTP/SFTP server?

Comment: There's no such thing, @ChrisF. You can have an FTP server such as `vsftpd`, which may or may not be configured to support not only FTP but also FTP/S, or you can have an SFTP server running under `sshd`